# Ways to manage & automate Chromium & Firefox updates & releases for Windows clients?

Tags: update, package-management, firefox, application, release-management

Given the privacy concerns & data stealing via Chrome & Microsoft browsers, we'd like to do this for our Windows client machines.

Here I am specifically asking about Firefox & Chromium and not Google Chrome.

https://superuser.com/questions/220759/what-are-the-differences-between-google-chrome-and-chromium-especially-with-res

- Google Chrome {closed source} auto updates and breaks things & locks things as it wants to at its own schedule.
- Chromium {open source} has to be manually updated and can get a bit cumbersome to do so, but if a way for managed automation exists it would *allow is* to **select update releases** at **our own schedule**.

  - Allowing user/ admin to choose which release version to update & install
  - Automates the updates process, but does not do any updates without explicit instruction or intervention.
  - Kind of how a Windows/ System Domain Manager chooses which updates to apply https://superuser.com/questions/539477/free-automated-os-independent-update-management-solutions

PS: https://superuser.com/questions/665311/is-there-an-application-or-some-other-method-that-would-update-chromium-in-windo

**This link specifies an automated way, but its not a 'managed' way where I can choose, which release version to update to, and when.**